# query and result on the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to look for a good example in asp.net MVC query controls and results.Aka posting controls values  and displaying result on the same page.

I Google on this but can't find any example

Comment: This is a massive question and completely dependent on any number of other factors. Are you trying to do it asynchronously? How "complex" is the model, and how much data is "all return data"? Start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I simplified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a crack at what I THINK you are after, which is having a form + results on the same page. I recently had the issue where I wanted that pattern, with the added complication that both methods (the form, and the form + results) needed to be GETs. Not a GET and a POST. Here's how I did it:

Controller methods:

```
// GET: /Reports/Refund
public ActionResult Refunds()
{
    var refundVM = new RefundCheckReportViewModel();
    return View(refundVM);
}

// GET: /Reports/Refund
public ActionResult RefundsResult(RefundCheckReportViewModel refundVM) 
{
    string errorMsg;
    var ready = refundVM.IsReadyToRun(out errorMsg);

    if (!ready)
        ModelState.AddModelError("StartDate", errorMsg);
    else
        refundVM.LoadReportData(); // this method on the ViewModel fetches the report data.

    return View("Refunds", refundVM);
}
```

View in Razor, which holds the form, plus the table for the report results:

```
@model MembershipCenter.ViewModels.Report.RefundCheckReportViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Refunds";
}

<div class="formStandard">


    @using (Html.BeginForm("RefundsResult", "Reports", FormMethod.Get))
    {

        <div class="fsHeader">
            <span class="reqLabel"><a class="req">*</a>required field</span>
            <strong>Refund Check Report</strong>
        </div>

         <div class="fsBlock">
            <div class="text">Date Range: <a class="req">*</a></div>
            <div class="elem">
                <span class="dateRangePicker">
                    From: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "short datepicker" })
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    To: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "short datepicker" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="fsFinalActions">
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" />
        </div>
    }

</div> <!-- end .formStandard -->



@if (Model.ReportData != null)
{
    if (Model.ReportData.Any()) {
        <table class="colorTable" style="margin-top: 30px;" id="resultTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Member #</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Check #</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (MembershipCenter.ViewModels.Report.RefundCheckReportViewModel.RefundReportResultItem item in Model.ReportData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.PrintedDate</td>
                        <td>@Html.GetMemberLink(item.MemberNumber)</td>
                        <td>@item.Amount</td>
                        <td>@item.CheckNumber</td>
                        <td>@item.PayeeName</td>
                        <td>@item.Reason</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else {
        <div><strong>There are not Refunds for the criteria above.</strong></div>
    }
}
```

And finally, for reference, my ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Membership = Biz.Business.Membership;
using Printing = Biz.Business.Printing;

namespace MembershipCenter.ViewModels.Report
{
    public class RefundCheckReportViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public List<RefundReportResultItem> ReportData = null;

        public RefundCheckReportViewModel()
        {
        }

        public bool IsReadyToRun(out string errorMessage)
        {
            errorMessage = string.Empty;

            if (!StartDate.HasValue || !EndDate.HasValue)
                errorMessage = "Please enter a start and end date";

            else if (StartDate.Value <= new DateTime(2012, 11, 1).Date)
                errorMessage = "Please enter a date greater than 11/1/2012 for the Start Date.";

            return (errorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty());
        }

        public void LoadReportData()
        {
            ReportData = new List<RefundReportResultItem>();

            var refunds = Membership.Getrefunds(blah);
            var checks = Printing.GetChecks(blah);

            foreach (var refund in refunds)
            {
                var check = checks.SingleOrDefault(c => c.RequestReferenceId == refund.Request.Id);
                if (check != null)
                    ReportData.Add(new RefundReportResultItem(refund, check));
            }
        }

        public class RefundReportResultItem
        {
            public int CheckNumber { get; set; }
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
            public string PayeeName { get; set; }
            public string MemberNumber { get; set; }
            public string Reason { get; set; }
            public string PrintedDate { get; set; }

            public RefundReportResultItem(Membership.Refund refund, Printing.PrintedCheck check)
            {
                MemberNumber = refund.MemberId;
                Reason = refund.Note;
                Amount = refund.Amount;

                PayeeName = check.Payee;
                CheckNumber = check.CheckNumber;
                PrintedDate = check.QueuedToPrint.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That `RefundReportResultItem` class under the ViewModel is a holder class for the data for each result item in the report.

Comment: thanks Graham, the idea of having ViewModel that contains request parameters and result it great!!!

Comment: Yeah, I found the style of "Fat ViewModel, Thin Controller, Stupid View" to be really, really helpful. The ViewModel should answer all questions about itself, and expose anything that a controller or view need to do their work, but nothing more. And I really love that from inside a controller, you can do: `return View("Refunds", refundVM);`, which takes lets you bind request to a different View, while passing along a Model.